# Google play apis - purchases.products.get for purchase validation gives 401 OAuth2 error

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-play-services, service-accounts

I aim to fetch purchases from googleapis by using a service account on **server-side**.

[Method: purchases.products.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get?apix_params=%7B%22packageName%22%3A%22com.mergedomhomedesign.game%22%2C%22productId%22%3A%22mdhd_bundle_2%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22.eyJzdWIiOiJtZXJnZWRvbS1zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnRAbWVyZ2Vkb20taG9tZS1kZXNpZ24uaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2ZpcmVzdG9yZS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS8iLCJpc3MiOiJtZXJnZWRvbS1zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnRAbWVyZ2Vkb20taG9tZS1kZXNpZ24uaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NTExNDgzMTgsImlhdCI6MTY1MTE0NDcxOH0.JDsEwHMlrxexs1WXVrfRxXiuip4kLadcGfvb-ZoE4-idy4acC02uxy8EFqlfQh5T50soNzue_ykZgpkEJBJl8cus5eW0PLj1BhqqmdJUo6FD5f-Hv6UzINsW94-NqQvBaI12QjGH8nkqMT7SwytGGFWFOCm1N6P2xSzZTw06gAl-G7TYtB5PN7fh_lJmWP4nqnF-rkw-5ggmjMEuacIe91pML790zdIeCZoXbiVOZ4l9sQoDzQT-G1kHQdH3CiE8bFpPLJ5_XfaLoxj5Bdfe3ArZZpX2zp8EhORfY29JlHrb1mdwNc40L8HIN0Cx827xGuOVSwtdfaX65FpZiQOHDg%22%7D#authorization-scopes) api requires an **oauth2** authentication.

Therefore I create an oauth2 token -from the client-secret.json I am provided from consolce.cloud.google- inside of my server-side **backend java spring** application.

```
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/client_secret.json")).createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher");
    googleCredentials.refresh();
    AccessToken accessToken = googleCredentials.getAccessToken();
```

The token I generate is like **'ya29.c.b0AXczHcuLszNI................'**
It ends with multiple dots I don't know why.

> [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/products/{productId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/products/%7BproductId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)

After I get the token I do the **GET** request to this URL.
I gets the following error:

> "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential.
> Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
> authentication credential. See
> [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),

[image]

Why my token is not working? The way I use it, Is it wrong? And/or oauth2 token generation way is it wrong?

Comment: Header prefix bearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token is sent as an authorization header.  The access token should be prefexed with the term bearer as it is a bearer token.